# C, bit shift . 2 consecutive shifts

Tags: c

```
static inline void ext4_ext_store_pblock(struct ext4_extent *ex,
                     ext4_fsblk_t pb)
{
    ex->ee_start_lo = cpu_to_le32((unsigned long) (pb & 0xffffffff));
    ex->ee_start_hi = cpu_to_le16((unsigned long) ((pb >> 31) >> 1) &
                      0xffff);
}
```

This code is from linux kernel.
See last line. it does pb>>31 then >>1
Is this same as pb >> 32
why not do that?

thank you

EDITED:
thank you all. sent patch to ext4 maillist

Comment: What datatype is `pb`? IOW, what is `ext4_fsblk_t`?

Comment: typedef unsigned long long ext4_fsblk_t;

Comment: `pb` is guaranteed to be at least 64-bits. So shifting by 32 will ***not*** invoke undefined behavior. If anything, I'd have to guess that the whoever wrote that code was probably a little paranoid and wasn't sure of the nitty gritty details of the standard.

Comment: @Mysticial or, perhaps, parts of the code used to be 32-bit.

Comment: @AndersLind If discussion pops up in the mailing list, it would be nice if you bring an update here too. I just found your posting in the archive for those interested in looking up themself:  http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=%3c1359529078.28633.YahooMailNeo%40web164603.mail.gq1.yahoo.com%3e

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two approaches are not quite the same thing, depending on the underlying data types. The standard (C11, 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators) states that:

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

Hence, if you were to shift a 32-bit wide integer type 32 bits to the right, it would result in undefined behaviour. However, shifting it 31 bits and then another bit *is* well defined.

That particular point, while a reason why someone may do this, is probably moot in this particular case. Given your type is `unsigned long long` (guaranteed 64 bits width), there should be no difference between `(x >> 31) >> 1` and `x >> 32`.

However, if some platform actually defines `ext4_fsblk_t` as a 32-bit type (or if it's carried forward from an earlier implementation which allowed a 32-bit type <sup>(a)</sup>), you would find yourself having to resort to the two-stage shift to guarantee defined behaviour.

---

<sup>(a)</sup>: There was an interim stage between `ext3` and `ext4` which allowed `ext3` to move to 48 bits with its extents, a stepping stone on the way to `ext4` with its 64-bit data types. Prior to that, 8TB was the practical limit to file systems.

It's *possible,* though I haven't confirmed, that this code snippet is a hangover from that transition, before the underlying data types went up to 64 bits wide.

The type that came to be used, `sector_t`, was conditionally defined as either `u64` or `unsigned long`, which may explain why the code is there in the first place. In situations where it was defined as the latter, a two-stage shift may have been needed.

However, given that `ext4` has left this interim stage behind, I'm not sure the two-stage shift is needed any more. Best bet is to raise a change request and see if it gets shot down by the developers :-)

Comment: Well, shifting by 31 bits (for a signed 32-bit integer) already has the effect of copying the sign bit to all the bits. So I fail to see the purpose of shifting by 32.

Comment: @Mystical: It's unsigned so should be a logical shift.  I guess long long may be 32 bits though so this is to prevent undefined behavior in that case.

Comment: @Mystical, yes, that may apply for signed integers, but that's not necessarily the case here.

Comment: @GuySirton Oh now I see the comment. It's an `unsigned long long`. That's guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Comment: @Mystical: Maybe on some platform that guarantee doesn't hold or it's actually long.  Otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Uhm, ext4_fsblk_t is defined as long long (see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L73 ) according to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html this leads to a double word (64 bit) integer. Hence shifting by 32 should not lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @junix, that's info that wasn't made available with the question. I've since updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: @paxdiablo Well a minimum of research would have pointed that out. As ext4 defines 64 bit blocknumbers (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L72 ) ext4_fsblk_t is unlikely to be defined as 32-bit type as this would break the ext4 format.

Answer (score 4):

I could imagine that the code has ben copied from ext3 where [ext3_fsblk_t](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext3/ext3.h#L496) is defined as `unsigned long` (32 bits). In this case paxdiablo's argument was correct:

> The standard (C11, 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators) states that:
>
> > If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.
>
> Hence, if you shift a 32-bit integer 32 bits to the right, it's undefined. However, shifting it 31 bits and then another bit is defined.

For [ext4_fsblk_t](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L73) is defined as `unsigned long long` and `long long` is in turn [guaranteed to be 64 bit](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html) this code does not make sense anymore.

Comment: there is a config option to use the ext4 driver for ext2 and ext3 though, but not sure what effect that would have

Comment: @technosaurus As this option obviously won't change the type of ext4_fsblk_t I don't think there is an influence. But +1 for pointing this out. Thank you.